# Android httppost returns html doctype instead of string

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

in my AsyncTask class I've got this to fetch the data:

```
    BufferedReader in = null
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devId", _devId));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", _regId));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", _code));
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(_URL);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String result = in.readLine();

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {

    }
```

and in my action ( c# mvc action), I've got this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string RegisterDeviceId(string devId, string regId, string code)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, the code is {0}", code);
    }
```

but my result in the client is always < ! DOCTYPE html > (dont mind the white spaces)

P.s: the functionality of my action is just to test if I can send a post request with parameter and send a simple text back to client, which I failed so far. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the html that is returning from server?

Comment: < ! DOCTYPE html >... that's it, that's all it returns.. i tried change the Accept to text/plain but didn't work.